# How can I make the first sibling element have blue background except for when a different sibling element is hovered?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following elements:

```
<div>Timothy Gruns</div>
<div>Lawrence Fishly</div>
<div>Jackson Crolya</div>
```

I want the background color to change to blue when hovered, but if none of them are hovered, I would like the first element to be blue.  So by default it would look like this:

[image]

If the 3rd element was hovered it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap all 3 divs in a container you can use the `:first-child` and the  `:hover` selectors to achieve this:

```css
div.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
div.container > div:first-child {
  background: blue;
}
div.container:hover > div {
  background: white;
}
div.container > div:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Timothy Gruns</div>
  <div>Lawrence Fishly</div>
  <div>Jackson Crolya</div>
</div>
```

1. Set the border/margin/padding for the inner divs.
2. Set default background of the first inner-div is blue.
3. When hovering the container - all inner divs gets white background
4. When hovering a div inside the container - that div gets a red background.

> You can set your own colors :) this is just for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve similar results is to reverse ordering of names (so the 'first' one is the last sibling tag) and display result the way you want with the help of `display: flex;`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.child {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.child:last-of-type {
  background-color: #72d5f1;
}

.child:hover ~ .child {
  background-color: inherit;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: #72d5f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Jackson Crolya</div>
  <div class="child">Lawrence Fishly</div>
  <div class="child">Timothy Gruns</div>
</div>
```